# Receive updates of starred projects via email of commits on master branch

Tags: github, notifications

I've starred a project on GitHub. I'd like to receive via email notification of major updates of that project (basically commits on the master branch).

I know there is the "Watch" options but I don't really want to receive emails for all issues and so on, I just want official updates on the project.

How can I do this?

Comment: Also AFAIK watching a project doesn't give you anyway what I'm asking for, even if you receive all notifications it's only on issues and pull requests, not a proper commit notification on the master branch, am I wrong on this?

Comment: You're right. If you want to receive e-mail notifications for commits on projects you are watching, you might want to have a look at this project: https://github.com/AurelienLourot/github-commit-watcher (Disclaimer: I'm the original author).

Comment: @Aurelien wow your script looks pretty nice! I'll play some with it for sure ;) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is finally a super simple service doing right what is needed

https://sibbell.com/

Get with github account, and you can get notification of new releases based on watch and/or stars. Totally free! It can get even more granular on a per base repository filter with some premium features, totally awesome!

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, There's no way** to do this through Github.com web/desktop interface

Here's what I have found (some I've tried) and I list in order of BEST to WORST solution:

1. **Zapier**:

   Does *EXACTLY WHAT YOU WANT and THEN SOME*... it will let you configure:

   - user
   - repo
   - branch
     .

   and then allows you to filter on what looks like all the GitHub API fields (well over 20+) like:

   - committer name
   - commit id
   - commit message
   - commit time
   - tag
   - etc...
     .

   It then creates a custom, private RSS feed that you can consume however you want and set up whatever alerting you need (desktop, mobile, ...whatever).  **https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/rss/3489/post-github-notifications-rss/**
   .

   ***COST:***

   Unfortunately, the **Zapier Free Tier** allows for only:

   - up to 5 "zaps" (analogous to IFTTT's recipes - [see below]),  and
   - up to 100 events/triggers/actions per month.
     .

   Although, this doesn't compare to IFTTT's free and unlimited recipes and events, I think it's still a good backup for those uniques situations that IFTTT just isn't robust enough for.

   In any event, I think you can get full, unlimited funcationality with a 14-day free trial, which you can then downgrade to the **Free Tier**.

   ---
2. **IFTTT**:

   If you haven't tried **IFTTT** yet, you should drop what you're doing, and check it out ASAP.

   Here are some instructions for building a recipe for per-commit email notifications:  **http://www.warski.org/blog/2013/04/per-commit-e-mail-github-notifications/**

   I'm sure you could find even more recipes on the IFTTT.com.
   .

   ***COST:***

   IFTTT is completely **free** with unlimited recipes and triggers/events/actions

   ---
3. Use a browser RSS extension that allows you to filter on keywords that would trigger on info about major releases.

   Here's a Chrome Extension (the ***SPOI*** filter RSS extension) that will do this for *Feedly*:  **https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spoi-filter/eepgdapnfglikioooabknaoadejkhini**
   .

   ***COST:***

   The SPOI filter RSS extension is completely **free**

   ---
4. Finally, you can also try http://www.hubnotify.com/.

   This works well, but only notifies by email when there is an update to something you are watching, so no filtering, bells & whistles, or ways to determine if a major commit has occurred.

   On the other hand, it:

   - has a clean interface
   - is simple and easy to use
   - allows you to see all the repos you are watching in one place, and...
   - choose which of those to get alerts for, and...
   - further whether to receive them:

     1. immediately
     2. daily
     3. weekly
     4. monthly

   .

   ***COST:***

   HubNotify is completely **free**

Comment: IFTTT looks like an awesome app, and your finding is indeed a good point, too bad not a native solution on github is available for such a simple and imo basic feature. +1 indeed, probably accepted answer as soon as I played around with IFTTT a bit ;)

Comment: good luck.  oh... as for Zapier, which is more robust than IFTTT.  With a FREE Zapier account, you can in fact have up to 5 "zaps" (analogous to IFTTT's recipes),  and up to 100 events/triggers/actions... which is not many, granted, but for those uniques situations that IFTTT just can't handle, it might be a nice "extra" option.

Comment: Well after tinkering, IFTTT worked as intended and it's quite functional! For now this is my accepted answer indeed, nice finding!

Comment: HubNotify gives notifications for new tags, not new commits, according to their own description.

Answer (score -1):

You can change it in notification center:

https://github.com/settings/notifications

Comment: As said above, I know about the notifications panels, but its REALLY limited on what you can get notified. You can't filter notifications of projects you are watching, it's all or nothing opt in.